# How to run code just after signals and events in QT QWidget initiation are processed?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

app = QApplication([])


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.list_widget = QListWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.currentRowChanged.connect(self.on_cur_row_changed)
        self.list_widget.addItems(['apple', 'orange'])

        # code block A # start #
        self.clear_qt_currentRow()
        # code block A # end   #

        print('End of MyDialog.__init__')

    def on_cur_row_changed(self, row):
        print('Current row changed to: ', row)

    def clear_qt_currentRow(self):
        print('Clear Qt currentRow')
        self.list_widget.selectionModel().clear()


dialog = MyDialog()
dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

As in code above, I don't like QT to set the currentRow property of list widget to 0(the first row).**I'd like to run code inside clear_qt_currentRow(), after after signals and events in QT QWidget initiation are processed(In this case, setting the currentRow property to None)** But self.clear_qt_currentRow() in code block A run too early(before QT changing the currentRow). The result showed as:

```
Clear Qt currentRow
End of MyDialog.__init__
Current row changed to:  0
```

Then, I tried below two alternatives for code block A but still didn't get self.clear_qt_currentRow() to run late enough.

```
# alternative 1
app.processEvents()
self.clear_qt_currentRow()

# result:
# Clear Qt currentRow
# End of MyDialog.__init__
# Current row changed to:  0
```

```
# alternative 2
QTimer.singleShot(0, self.clear_qt_currentRow)

# result:
# End of MyDialog.__init__
# Clear Qt currentRow
# Current row changed to:  0
```

I know that QTimer.singleShot(10000, self.clear_qt_currentRow) can make it. But it can't be a "real" solution because users may have computers with different specs.

Any suggestion for me?

Edit: add what I want to do in BOLD text.

Edit: with help from @zariiii9003, I change to below code, which does the job inside the class.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

app = QApplication([])


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.list_widget = QListWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.currentRowChanged.connect(self.on_cur_row_changed)
        self.list_widget.addItems(['apple', 'orange'])
        # code block A # start #
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.clear_qt_currentRow)
        # code block A # end   #
        print('End of MyDialog.__init__')

    def on_cur_row_changed(self, row):
        print('Current row changed to: ', row)

    def clear_qt_currentRow(self):
        print('Process events')
        # add here
        app.processEvents()
        print('Clear Qt currentRow')
        self.list_widget.selectionModel().clear()


dialog = MyDialog()
dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I don't understand your question very well, could you explain me better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at Spyder, an IDE that is implemented with Qt:

If you look [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/68b215729f63737bf71fbb7e191c8d1401f7c709/spyder/app/mainwindow.py#L4127):

```
    # Main window
    main = MainWindow(options)

    main.show()
    main.post_visible_setup()
```

they first initialize the MainWindow, then they call `show()` and then they perform a `post_visible_setup()`.

For your case, this:

```
dialog = MyDialog()
dialog.show()
app.processEvents()
dialog.clear_qt_currentRow()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

results in

```
End of MyDialog.__init__
Current row changed to:  0
Clear Qt currentRow
Current row changed to:  -1
```